# Group Json attributes in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need group the displays by sectors, looked for some method to do this but not found in json.
The code:

```
$(function displays(){   
var url = '{% url get_displays %}';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {  
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
        $.each(data, function(i, c) {               
            sidebar.append('<ul>'+c.fields.setor.fields['nome']+'<li>'+c.fields['nome']+' - '+c.fields['janelas']+'</li>'+'</ul>');             
    }); ///close each           
}); ///close getJson
}); ///close function
```

The Image show two objects in same setor Valença but separated:
 
http://postimage.org/image/myc7xsgwh/

JSON output:

```
[
{
    "pk": 2, 
    "model": "display.display", 
    "fields": {
        "data_criacao": "2012-03-27", 
        "setor": {
            "pk": 2, 
            "model": "display.setor", 
            "fields": {
                "nome": "Rio de Janeiro"
            }
        }, 
        "janelas": 12, 
        "nome": "Restaurante"
    }
}, 
{
    "pk": 3, 
    "model": "display.display", 
    "fields": {
        "data_criacao": "2012-03-27", 
        "setor": {
            "pk": 1, 
            "model": "display.setor", 
            "fields": {
                "nome": "Valença"
            }
        }, 
        "janelas": 12, 
        "nome": "Loja de Roupas Dimais"
    }
}, 
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "display.display", 
    "fields": {
        "data_criacao": "2012-03-27", 
        "setor": {
            "pk": 1, 
            "model": "display.setor", 
            "fields": {
                "nome": "Valença"
            }
        }, 
        "janelas": 12, 
        "nome": "Shopping"
    }
}
]
```

How to group this two displays in same "setor"?

Editing:

Using Django Framework is possible regroup the attributes:

```
# queryset

displays = Display.objects.filter(janelas__lte=12).select_related('setor').order_by('setor__nome')

# template

 {% regroup displays by setor as setor_list %}

<ul>
{% for s in setor_list %}
<li>{{ s.grouper }}
<ul>
    {% for d in s.list %}
    <li>{{ d.nome }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The DOC:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

Also try to do through Jquery.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you could do that on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object from the existing data

```
var tmp = {};

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var nome = item.fields.setor.fields.nome;
    if (!tmp[nome]) {
        tmp[nome] = [];
    }
    tmp[nome].push(item);

});
```

Then loop over new object to generate html

Not sure how you wanted list separated so I used H3 tag and I didn't include all variables you are parsing:

```
var html = [];
$.each(tmp, function(key, item) {
    html.push('<h3>' + key + '</h3><ul>');
    $.each(item, function(i, val) {
        html.push('<li>' + 'pk:' + val.pk + ', nome:' + val.fields.nome + '</li>')
    })
    html.push('</ul>');
});
 $('.sidebar').append(html.join(''));
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xrtpD/1/

Comment: Thanks for the code charlietfl!
I will try your code soon. I did in the server-side, following the code.